# IBM MobileFirst Analytics Error

Tags: mobilefirst-analytics

I am keep getting below error frequently in messages.log on for IBM MF Analytics server 8.0 deployed on Liberty server 8.5.5.9.

ibm.mobile.analytics.server.processors.v1.ProcessorUtilityV1 W MSAN239W: Could not populate stackTrace using the key $stacktrace, returning null.

Anyone let me know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known APAR: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1PI70463
To resolve, go to IBM Fix Central and download the latest iFix for IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0.

Comment: Thanks. i will download the fix and apply it.

Comment: May I know, if this issue has been resolved? If yes, in which fix pack?

Comment: This question is from February... download the latest iFix, it’ll have the fix.